# bluemix cannot login, stop/restart applications

Tags: node.js, authentication, ibm-cloud, iot

I cannot stop/restart an sample program from http://m2m.demos.ibm.com/trafficsimulator.html. It gives the following errors:
"BXNUI0018E: Instances for the 'undefined' application could not be retrieved".

After I to refreshes the dashboard, I cannot login.
"BXNUI0303E: The account information could not be retrieved because of a problem contacting the business support system. You will be logged out of Bluemix.

Try again later. If you see this message again, go to DOCS and select Troubleshooting for help and support options."

anyone can help me out?

Based on my experience, it seems that Bluemix IoT service is not quite stable.

Thanks,
Jun

Answer (score 1):

At the moment https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ is available while https://console.ng.bluemix.net/ is still recovering.

Comment: Now Bluemix is back on all regions.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to a temporary platform issue.
You could find updates about the platform status on

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Login issues in US-SOUTH, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions.
Users are experiencing issues during login in the US-SOUTH, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions (slow login / errors). The team is continuing to investigating.
Updated:    Nov 11, 2015 8:49 AM UTC+0100
Starts: Nov 11, 2015 8:00 AM UTC+0100
Category:   Bluemix Platform
Region(s):  au-syd
eu-gb
us-south

Edit at 2:35pm UTC+1 11/11/2015 
The issue on Bluemix Login service has been solved.

RESOLVED: Login issues in US-SOUTH, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions.
Users are experiencing issues during login in the US-SOUTH, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions (slow login / errors). The team is continuing to investigating.

Update: This issue is now resolved, sorry for any inconvenience this might have caused.

Ends:   Nov 11, 2015 12:44 PM UTC+0100

Comment: Ok the steps I suggest are to logout from Bluemix and all related pages, then clear caches and cookies on the browser and then try again: it could related with a problem with your login session

Comment: i switched the browser from Chrome to IE. the problem still exists.

Comment: Hi, checking on Bluemix Status I found this alert, issued more than one hour ago, regarding login problems:

Login issues in US-SOUTH, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions.
Users are experiencing issues during login in the US-SOUTH, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions (slow login / errors). The team is continuing to investigating.
Updated: Nov 11, 2015 8:49 AM UTC+0100
Starts: Nov 11, 2015 8:00 AM UTC+0100
Category: Bluemix Platform
Region(s): au-syd
eu-gb
us-south

Comment: yes, it is... that's why i think the service is not stable... sometimes, it is also very slow. Not sure how Azure and AWS's IoT platforms go.

Comment: Bluemix is a younger platform that provide a lot of technologies and solutions not available on the other platforms. Integrating such different kind of environments sometimes has some problems but is becoming more stable everyday. And on IoT it offers solutions far better than the others.